# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server(In Asp.net Mvc applciation )

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

Here i am creating login page to check validateUSer but i got exception:
Here i posted my full code please check it once...
[image]

```
enter code here

namespace Loginusingmvc.Controllers
 {
   public class LoginController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Login/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogIn(string returnUrl = "")
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return LogOut();
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
   // [HttpPost]
    public  bool ValidateUser(string UserID, string Password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserID) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
            return false;

        using (ntc_salesEntities context = new ntc_salesEntities())
        {
            var user = (from u in context.user_master
                        where String.Compare(u.UserID, UserID, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                              && String.Compare(u.Password, Password, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                         select u).FirstOrDefault();

            return user != null;
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(user_master model, string returnUrl = "")
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserID,model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.UserID,false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login details are wrong.");
            }

        }
        return View(model);

    }


    public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }




}
```

}

Route:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default1",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = 
              UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Html

```
    @model Loginusingmvc.Models.user_master

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "LogIn";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>LogIn</h2>


    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login Failed, check details")

<div>
       @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", new { returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post))
        {

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login Form</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u=> u.UserID)</div>
        <div class="editor-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(u=> u.UserID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u=> u.UserID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u=> u.Password)</div>
        <div  class="editor-field">@Html.PasswordFor(u=> u.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u=> u.Password)
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="Login" />

    </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

web.config

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Loginusingmvc-20140516104010;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Loginusingmvc-20140516104010.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="LoginEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Login.csdl|res://*/Models.Login.ssdl|res://*/Models.Login.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=206.225.85.212;user id=ntc;password=NTC@123;database=ntc_sales&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="ntc_salesEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=;user id=ntc;password=NTC@123;database=ntc_sales&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="DAConnection" connectionString="Data Source=206.225.85.212;user id=;database=" providerName="MySql.Data.MySQLClient" />
```

```
<membership defaultProvider="mysqlprovider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="mysqlprovider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DAConnection"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: by seeing this post i enable the http://www.aspdotnet-sharepoint.com/2012/04/network-related-or-instance-specific.html  tcp

Comment: Something wrong with database connection. Nothing else.

Comment: what i am doning with membership connection is it correct?

Comment: Looks like it is correct, but I cannot say that about connection string itself. You should make sure it is ok.

Comment: Have you installed mysql provider(or connector)?

Comment: i used validationuser for entity and membership for mysql connection but both credientials are same is it correct?

Comment: yes i installed @Andrei Mikhalevich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you `ConnectionString`. You definitly got this error because app cannot establish connection with the databse.

As far as you are using MySql, I would recommend you to implement custom membership provider to control all the aspects of authentication, and be able to debug your code. Here is how to proceed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

If you still want to go with SqlMembershipProvider, try this, hope it helps:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
          type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, mysql.web"
            connectionStringName="DAConnection"
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
            enablePasswordReset="true"
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
            requiresUniqueEmail="true"
            passwordFormat="Hashed"
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
            minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
            minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
            passwordAttemptWindow="10"                            
            applicationName="/"
            autogenerateschema="true"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Found there: http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/02/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-membership-provider-6-2-2-porting-to-mono-part-2-of-3/

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'mysql.web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: i had tried all blogs solution still now i didn't for solution for below error "Could not load file or assembly 'mysql.web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: @sandeep implement custom membership provider. It will help you a lot.